# Finding plane equation given two lines

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry, 3d

Determine an equation of the plane containing the lines $\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y+1}{-1}=\frac{z-5}{6}$; $r=\lt1,-1,5\gt+t\lt1,1,-3\gt$.

I calculated the cross product between the directional vector of both lines to find the normal vector $n$, but when I looked for an intersection point $r_0$ to apply the formula: $\lt r-r_0\gt \bullet \ \ n$, I did not find any.

Can I use the point $\lt1,-1,5\gt$ given in the line $r$? Or is it not possible to find an equation of the plane containing two lines that do not intersect?

Comment: Yes, you can use the $(1,-1,5)$. See my answer below.

Comment: Please correct the title of this question. The lines DO intersect at (1,-1,5). Plug in x=1,y=-1 and z=5 into the first line, and you get 0=0=0.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The first line is given by $$L_1:\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y+1}{-1}=\frac{z-5}{6}$$ and the symmetric form of the other line is $$L_2:\frac{x-1}{1}=\frac{y+1}{1}=\frac{z-5}{-3}.$$ Clearly, $L_1\cap L_2$ is the point $(1,-1,5)$. Clearly, $L_1$ and $L_2$ are not parallel. Write $$V_1=2\hat{i}-\hat{j}+6\hat{k}$$ and $$V_2=\hat{i}+\hat{j}-3\hat{k}.$$ 
Then,
$$V_1\times V_2=
\begin{vmatrix}
\hat{i}&\hat{j}&\hat{k}\\
2&-1&6\\
1&1&-3\\
\end{vmatrix}=\hat{i}(3-6)-\hat{j}(-6-6)+\hat{k}(2+1)=-3\hat{i}+12\hat{j}+3\hat{k}.$$
Thus, the equation of the plane containing $L_1$ and $L_2$ is given by
$$-3(x-1)+12(y+1)+3(z-5)=0.$$ That is, $$-3x+12y+3z=0.$$

Comment: why the down vote? can you please explain?

Comment: I don't know who downvoted or why, but it might be because the lines _do_ intersect.

Comment: @David K Thank you for pointing my mistake. I did an edit to my answer.--)

Comment: Why did you take the cross product of their direction vectors??

Comment: @Hydrous Caperilla The cross product is by definition perpendicular to both $V_1$ and $V_2$ and hence this cross product serves as a normal vector to the plane that contains $L_1$ and $L_2$

Comment: What happens if the lines are parallel as the cross product is then zero?

Comment: @twa14 If the lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ are parallel and noncoincident then you can apply the same approach as in the above solution. Just create another line $L_3$ that contains a point in $L_1$ and a point in $L_2$. Then work on the intersecting lines $L_1$ and $L_3$.

Answer (score 5):

You should go back and check your work. The point $(1,-1,5)$ obviously satisfies the first equation, and the lines aren’t parallel, so if you’re not getting that as the point of intersection you’re making a mistake somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 2):

<1,−1,5> is a point on both lines so yes you can use it as it is in the plane.